# Talend parse Date "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000Z'"

Tags: salesforce, talend

I have an error parsing a date in Talend.
My input is an excel file as String and my output is a Date with the following Salesforce format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000Z'"

I have a tMap with this connection

> TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000Z'",Row1.firstDate)

but is throwing the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable
>   date: "2008-05-11T12:02:46.000+0000"  at
>   routines.TalendDate.parseDate(TalendDate.java:895)

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TalendDate.parseDate, the parameter "pattern" must match the pattern of the input String, and not the pattern of the Date you want in the output.

You can try :

```
TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000+0000'",Row1.firstDate )
```

Formatting of Date output is accessible in the 'schema' menu, in "Date Model" column.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

TalendDate.parseDate("MM/dd/yyyy",'T'HH:mm:ss',Row1.firstDate);