# Talend parse date to SalesForce

Tags: java, date, type-conversion, talend

i want to parse a string date in salesforce, but i had this error message :

****Exception in component tMap_1 (LSH_SM_UpsertResidenceHistory_V2_Copy9_Copy1_Copy_Copy_Copy_Copy2)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun Jan 09 00:00:00 CET 29"
at routines.TalendDate.parseDate(TalendDate.java:942)
at routines.TalendDate.parseDate(TalendDate.java:886)**

BTW, in the tmap i'm using this code to convert the date to salesforce format :
**TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000+0000'",row4.SalingAgreementDate__c)**

i really don't know what is the problem here ! HELP !!

Comment: My advise: Write some Tests if you haven't. Looks like a parsing issue..

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the input "Sun Jan 09 00:00:00 CET 29" does not match your input pattern "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000+0000'"

PLease change the Input from source in a preprocessing or configuration of the date output, see:

[Talend parse Date "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000Z'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43755262/talend-parse-date-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-000z)

or change your format pattern set in your method call.

Comment: But, the source date is in a normal format : 12-07-2020

Comment: Not when your function is called.
Unparseable date: "Sun Jan 09 00:00:00 CET 29"

And if the source date would be in a format like you mentioned now "12-07-2020", this will not work if you try applying the format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000+0000"

Please investigate the complete process

Comment: look, the file source is an XML file, then i convert the date column to string to use it in other string columns, finally i want to reconvert it in a date format to load it to salesforce.

Comment: This process is not covered in your question. I assume that this "Unparseable date: "Sun Jan 09 00:00:00 CET 29" at routines.TalendDate.parseDate(TalendDate.java:942) at routines.TalendDate.parseDate(TalendDate.java:886)" happens where you do this "TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000+0000'",row4.SalingAgreementDate__c)"

So please debug/write out the value of row4.SalingAgreementDate__c before calling "TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000+0000'",row4.SalingAgreementDate__c)"

because the format patterns do not match and will run into an Exception.

Comment: ok i understand, do you know how to convert this string date (Sun Jan 09 00:00:00 CET 29) to salesforce format ? i'm really stuck with that

Comment: If you really want to bring "Sun Jan 09 00:00:00 CET 29" to something usable with your method pattern:

DateFormat osLocalizedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
System.out.println(osLocalizedDateFormat.format(new Date()))

then:

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'.000+0000'");  
String strDate = dateFormat.format(osLocalizedDateFormat.format(new Date()));